# Downloading a data file from webpage into desired file location by "clicking" on "button"

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am hoping someone can help with the following. I am attempting to automate the downloading of file from a website using VBA.

I am using the below code, however this saves a csv file into the desired path. What I want to do is "click" the download link and have the file save to a specified path instead.

The inspect element information on the webpage is as follows:

```
input type="hidden" name="download" value=""

a href="#" onclick="var dl_var = find_control('download'); dl_var.value = '1'; submitFormByPost(dl_var.form); dl_var.value = ''; return false;">
                        <img src="/i/prices_export_excel.gif" height="48" width="48" alt="Download to spreadsheet"><br>
                        download to spreadsheet
                    </a
```

I have tried looking at a range of different links however none seem to have the solution. 
My code is below.

```
Sub DownloadFile()

Dim myURL As String
myURL = "https://YourWebSite.com/?your_query_parameters"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
WinHttpReq.send

myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "C:\file.csv", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 =          overwrite
    oStream.Close
End If

End Sub`
```

Instead of saving the page I want to download the file to a desired file path.

Comment: you can try to use Application.SendKeys "%{S}" 'download the file when is open the pop up.

Comment: If you have a successful binary download (where you can easily specify download location) why would you want to automate to using a click which will require opening a browser and which adds a number of other obstacles to overcome?

Comment: Because I don’t want a binary download. I want the downloaded price data from the website, which gives historical prices in a format that I use in another workbook and is only accessible through the download button.

Comment: If you don't have a download url and need to click the button then you will need a browser based solution. Easy way is to click the download button, loop the download folder checking for new file (+1 file count) then shift that file (last modified date basis) to folder of choice with filesystemobject.

Comment: So I am unable to do this through a VBA solution?

Comment: Sorry my experience with interfacing outside of excel is limited

Answer (score 0):

I have a my own solution to download the file from web page and works.

1. reference(select): Microsoft Internet Controls, Microsoft HTML Object Library

an example of my code

```
Dim htmlDoc As HTMLDocument ' global variable
Dim myHtmlElement As IHTMLElement 'global variable
Sub test()
Dim dominio As String

dominio = "your url"

Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate dominio

'Do
'DoEvents
'Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set htmlDoc = ie.document

    Call ie.document.getElementById("tag_id_username").setAttribute("value", "your username")
    Call ie.document.getElementById("tag_id_password").setAttribute("value", "your password")

ie.document.getElementById("loginForm").Click 'button login

While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend

Call ie.document.getElementById("link_document_download").Click 

Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

Application.SendKeys "%{S}" ' download the file when is open the pop up

Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

This solution require that you have to keep open and focused the browser  otherwise the `application.SendKeys "{S}"` doesn't work.
If you don't have id tag you can use the classname (Set element = `ie.Document.querySelector(".classname"))`...

This file go in download folder(defalut).
you can read this post how to change path..
[How can I change the file path of a Workbook in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435814/how-can-i-change-the-file-path-of-a-workbook-in-vba)

Hope this helps

> EDIT POST AFTER YOUR COMMENT

remember to add this reference

[image]

The follow there is the code that i tried in your link and "works". With this code you can write in input tag username - password and click the button to login in your account. After we have to write next code to click on the download file...

```
Sub test()

Dim dominio, value As String
Dim myInput As Object

dominio = "https://www.steelbb.com"

Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate dominio

Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

For Each myInput In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input") 'Cells
    If myInput.Name = "username" Then
        Call myInput.setAttribute("value", "write your username")

    ElseIf myInput.Name = "password" Then
        Call myInput.setAttribute("value", "write your password")

    ElseIf myInput.Name = "doLogin" Then
        'Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Call myInput.Click
    End If
Next myInput

'Add next code after login


Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

> Second EDIT

IF the above code works for you add this code after comment
'Add next code after login
'----------------------download file

```
'Add next code after login
Do While ie.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

For Each myInput In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If myInput.href = "#" And myInput.onclick = "var dl_var = find_control('download'); dl_var.value = '1'; submitFormByPost(dl_var.form); dl_var.value = ''; return false;" Then
       myInput.Click
       ' wait 2 seconds we give the time to load the file and only when there is the pop up we can click save button
       Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)
       ' download the file when is open the pop up
       Application.SendKeys "%{S}"
       Exit For
    End If
Next myInput

Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

I tried this code with your input information present in your post

**INTO YOUR POST**

> The inspect element information on the webpage is as follows:
>
> input type="hidden" name="download" value=""
>
> a href="#" onclick="var dl_var = find_control('download');
>   dl_var.value = '1'; submitFormByPost(dl_var.form); dl_var.value = '';
>   return false;">
>                           
>                           download to spreadsheet

Comment: Do you know if you are able to also add the ability to put in the username and password?  Thanks

Comment: Yes if you see the code there is an example where you have to insert username and password...

Comment: I am unable to get the download click to work. from the html I posted above, are you able to discern what I need to enter for the “link_document_download”.

Comment: It is very hard in this situation because i don't have the all HTML page but we can try step by step. First step try only to make login...if it is OK after tell me about if the next page is that where there is the link to download the page...

Comment: I have included the element html for the download button above. Would it help if I gave you the full html of the page? It would be very long. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: This element where you download...is the first page after the login?

Comment: That’s correct. Even if I can just get it to download the element that is a win. As I can login and Then run the script to download. Thanks

Comment: Find the tag elements of your input login...and post the Ross so se understand which tags are...

Comment: Forse example Call ie.document.getElementById("tag_id_username").setAttribute("value", "your username")
    Call ie.document.getElementById("tag_id_password").setAttribute("value", "your password")

Comment: You can see the page I am trying to do it for at www.steelbb.com

Comment: @DP1242 i updated my post with new code. You can try the code and give me updated...Next Step is the page where we have to click on download link.

Comment: @DP1242 attention please, when you'll try the code write your username and your password into the code.

Comment: That has worked for the login page, thankyou. However still not working for the download click page. What would help to get this to work?

Comment: Can you post more HTML code where is the download link

Comment: Another...post the error when you try to execute the download code

Comment: Sorry for the delay

Comment: Do you have only this table where there is the download link?...and if you get an error can you post it?

Comment: Yes that is correct. No errors are given. It just logs in, then nothing happens

Comment: For Each myInput In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input") 'Cells
    If myInput.Name = "username" Then
        Call myInput.setAttribute("value", "write your username")

    ElseIf myInput.Name = "password" Then
        Call myInput.setAttribute("value", "write your password")

    ElseIf myInput.Name = "doLogin" Then
        'Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Call myInput.Click
    End If
Next myInput

Comment: I think that you have to continue to press F8 until finish the load page...

Comment: I did that. Once it has logged in it goes back to the myinout.name = dolphin then it throws an run time error 70. This is after it has logged in. So it doesn’t get into the second part of the code

Answer (score 0):

```
</td>
            <td>
            <table width=100%>
            <tr>
                            <td style="width:20px;"></td>

            <td align="center" width="100">
                <input type="hidden" name="download" value="" />
                <a href="#" onclick="var dl_var = find_control('download'); dl_var.value = '1'; submitFormByPost(dl_var.form); dl_var.value = ''; return false;">
                    <img src="/i/prices_export_excel.gif" height="48" width="48" alt="Download to spreadsheet" /><br />
                    download to spreadsheet
                </a>
            </td>

                            <td style="width:20px;"></td>

            <td align="center" width="100">
                <a href="#" onclick="graph_print(AmCharts.getExport(jQuery('#amcharts2_container').get(0))[0]); return false;">
                    <img src="/i/prices_graph_print.gif" height="48" width="51" alt="Print graph" /><br />
                    print graph
                </a>
            </td>

            <td style="width:20px;"></td>

            <td align="center" width="100">
                <a href="#" onclick="graph_download(AmCharts.getExport(jQuery('#amcharts2_container').get(0))[0]); return false;">
                    <img src="/i/prices_export_image.gif" height="48" width="51" alt="Export image" /><br />
                    export image
                </a>
            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>



    <div id="amcharts2_container" style="z-index: -1; width: 780px; height: 550px;"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">                 
        AmCharts.ready(function(){
```

Comment: I did that. Once it has logged in it goes back to the myinout.name = dolphin then it throws an run time error 70. This is after it has logged in. So it doesn’t get into the second part of the code.